# AES-based pseudo random

Tags: encryption, random, aes

I'm reading the paper "Concerto: A High Concurrency Key-Value Store with Integrity
".
For memory checking, they said they used AES-based pseudo random function, which has two input and outputs hash.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f78p.png)

My question is: **How to implement this AES-based pseudo random function in C or Go?** Is this just use AES to encrypt？ Someone can give me an example of implementation.

Comment: According to the paper, it's just AES-CMAC as described in RFC 4615.

Comment: Note that devs mainly think of a pseudo random function to produce a stream of random bits. A PRF such as HMAC or CMAC simply outputs a statically sized output, in this case 128 bits. What a horrid paper, I absolutely despise documents that use definitions out of the blue.

Comment: @RichardHeap. Does this mean that I can use AES-CMAC to encrypt the message(address, data), and the encryption result is the PRF result in this paper. And the key for encryption is whatever I want? Sorry to bother you. I don't know much about pseudo-random.

Comment: You simply have to read the paper, but I agree with Maarten - they rather gloss over the issue of how the PRF is used, instead concentrating on their optimizations to run very fast. To understand PRFs just search using google.